# Data structure for counting occurrences

Tags: java, duplicates, multiset, bag

Say I have an array

```
[bob, alice, jeff, bob, bob]
```

I would like to transform this array into

```
[bob, alice, jeff, bob1, bob2]
```

That is, determining occurrences.

```
// iterate through array
// check if element is in finalArray
     // if not add to finalArray
// if found in final array
    // add in duplicateArray
   // check instances of element in duplicateArray and add that number to element
   // insert element+updated number to finalArray
```

This is my implementation of the above algorithm

```
     ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
    list.add("Bob");
    list.add("Jane");
    list.add("Smith");
    list.add("Bob");
    list.add("Bob");
    list.add("Jane");
    list.add("Smithery");

    ArrayList<String> finalList = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<String> tempList = new ArrayList<>();

    for(String name : list) {
        if(finalList.contains(name)) {
            int count = 0;
            tempList.add(name);
            for(int i=0; i < tempList.size(); i++) {
                if(tempList.get(i) == name) {
                    count++;
                }
            }
            String tempName = name + count;
            finalList.add(tempName);
        } else {
            finalList.add(name);
        }
    }
    for(String name: finalList) {
        System.out.println(name);
    }
```

My question is although `ArrayList`, and other data structure have `.contains` method, do any data structures have methods that return the number of instances of the element in the data structure?

Comment: You can use Map for above-mentioned flow.

Comment: [`MultiSet`](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiset). Guava provides [an implementation](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/21.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Multiset.html).

Comment: Is this question about finding a collection type that is suitable or finding a way to extract objects so that duplicates are uniquely numbered?

Comment: You probably want a counting map for this. `Map<String, Integer> wordToCount`. It's typically also called `MultiSet` or `Bag`. But as you see, it is just a `Map` which maps a word to its number of occurrences. Its `contains` is very fast (as opposed to `ArrayList`). With `get` u can grab the current count and with `put` you can update it (increment by one as you iterate through the array). Alternatively, you can make everything much more compact using the newer `compute` methods.

Comment: Questions asking for *homework help* **must** include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the difficulty you are having solving it ([help], [ask]).

Comment: This wasn't homework, it was a problem I encountered on a practice problem. I can post the coding solution that I came up with that seemed more inefficient. @Zab

Comment: Yes, please. That shows your effort which yields to up votes.

Comment: @Zabuza Posted my solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
List<String> data = ...;
List<String> finalData = new ArrayList<>();
Map<String, Integer> counts = new HashMap<>();

for(String s : data) {
    counts.merge(s, 1, Integer::sum);  // Keep track of occurences seen

    int occurences = counts.get(s);  // Get how many there are for s

    if(occurences == 1) { 
        finalData.add(s);
    }
    else {  // if more than 1, change the string
        finalData.add(s + (occurences - 1));
    }
}
```

Now the real question is, what happens when you have "Bob" in the List twice, and "Bob1" is also in the original list...

Comment: The real question of what happens when Bob is in the List twice and how to approach that question in an efficient manner is the whole point of the question.

Comment: But this does work, and is more efficient than yours and shorter.  With input `List<String> data = List.of("Bob", "Jane", "Smith", "Bob", "Bob", "Jane", "Smithery")` it gives `[Bob, Jane, Smith, Bob1, Bob2, Jane1, Smithery]`

Comment: Ah you're right! Sorry! I'll upvote when it allows me to!

Answer (score 0):

This is my current coding implementation that does work.

```
     ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
    list.add("Bob");
    list.add("Jane");
    list.add("Smith");
    list.add("Bob");
    list.add("Bob");
    list.add("Jane");
    list.add("Smithery");

    ArrayList<String> finalList = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<String> tempList = new ArrayList<>();

    for(String name : list) {
        if(finalList.contains(name)) {
            int count = 0;
            tempList.add(name);
            for(int i=0; i < tempList.size(); i++) {
                if(tempList.get(i) == name) {
                    count++;
                }
            }
            String tempName = name + count;
            finalList.add(tempName);
        } else {
            finalList.add(name);
        }
    }
    for(String name: finalList) {
        System.out.println(name);
    }
```